# Software that Controls and Limits Connections made by programs/services/windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, networking, network-monitor, network-administration

I'm looking for a software that shows me clear and detailed data for all my PC's Network Resources Usage (including Ping affection, Upload/Download Rate). I need it enables me to control (Block/Limit) every connection of any Process (Application or windows activity).

---

*Operating System:* **Microsoft Windows 8.1**

---

### Previous Experience

*NetLimiter:* Unfortunately seems unstable on Windows 8.1 for now.

*NetBalancer:* Unfortunately not free